# Would taking up an associate's degree after finishing your bachelor's harm your resume?

Tags: career-path

Would taking up an associate's degree after finishing your bachelor's harm your resume?

Comment: When your goal after finishing your college-level education is...?

Comment: I agree, @Jay, if you want to know whether taking up an associate's degree after getting a bachelors would help with grad school, then perhaps you should edit your answer, otherwise I would vote to migrate this as off-topic.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The simple answer, for the most general case, is *no*.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple degrees would by no means harm your resume. Listing a degree that has absolutely no relation to the job you are applying for may. The answer to this question depends on what you are trying to accomplish, whether it be to have another line item on your resume or to actually obtain a degree related to the field in which you entering. It never hurts to learn more. The only thing you may lose

http://careersteering.com/executiveresume/education-on-resume/
http://www.genpink.com/10-things-to-quit-putting-on-your-resume/